# How can I set a specific switch to true / false within a table?

Tags: reactjs

How can I use React to react when I click on a switch within a table so that only the clicked switch is activated or deactivated?
At the moment all switches are always set to true / false.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({checkedA: true});

 <TableCell align="right">
        <ToggleButton welcheListe={welcheListe}></ToggleButton>

           <FormControlLabel 
            control={
                  <Switch
                    checked={state.checkedA}
                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                    name="checkedA"
                   />
                    }
             label="exakte Suche"
           />
 </TableCell>


const handleChange = (event) => {
 setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
};
```

[image]

Comment: `onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}` - You have added `onChange` event handler on `Switch` component which means `handleChange` function will be called when the switch is toggled.

Comment: We need to see the entire component. Where is `handleChange()`, and the other `<Switch />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you still haven't provided the code for the second `<Switch />`, you should set the initial `state` for all of your `<Switch />`s, like so:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({checkedA: true, checkedB: false}); // include all names

 
  <Switch
      checked={state.checkedA}
      onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
      name="checkedA"
  />

  <Switch
      checked={state.checkedB}
      onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
      name="checkedB"
  />


const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState(prevState => {    // use previous state
        ...prevState,
        [event.target.name]: !prevState[event.target.name]    // set to opposite of previous value
    });
};
```

Make sure you are using the correct part of `state` for each `<Switch />`: `checked={state.checked__}`. I improved the `handleChange()` function as well to use previous `state`.